# Can a "mini" electromagnet propel a magnet 20 cm or so in the air

Tags: electromagnetism, magnet

I have an idea to DIY a little thing that would require to throw a piece about 20 cm into the air (straight up).

My idea is the following: To have a mini electromagnet (such as [this one](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32827668925.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.17fc153bTeVJJ1&algo_pvid=52793bdc-4c8a-460f-8016-abf89473d6da&algo_expid=52793bdc-4c8a-460f-8016-abf89473d6da-1&btsid=0b0a0ae215975784531286772e94a0&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)  ) and to have a permanent magnet attached to the bottom of my piece. I'd first have the electromagnet pulling the piece, and then instantly switch the polarity in order to repel the said magnet and hopefully propel it upward.

And my question is: could this even work? Assuming the piece to propel is only the magnet, how big of an electromagnet and of a permanent magnet would it require?

Thanks.

Comment: What would stop your magnet flipping over to be attracted to the electromagnet again?

Comment: well, good point. The end goal is to have the magnet glue to the inside a 5 cm box. So this might be enough to prevent the flip?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. Electro-magnets are highly inductive. That means you can't reverse the current instantly. How much electrical theory do you know? Can you figure out how long it will take to reverse the current through the solenoid if you flip the voltage? If you can do that how does that relate to the amount of time it would take for the magnet to flip? Note that there is no datasheet for the device you are considering so you have no specification for the inductance.

Comment: @Transistor unfortunately I don't have much knowledge. But if reversing the polarity cannot be done instantly, what about simply switching it on directly with the repelling polarity while the permanent magnet is lying on the electromagnet?

Comment: I'd think it's still going to flip.

Comment: It would certainly be a fun experiment. You would need to block Flyback with a large power Zener to increase L/R =Tau during cutoff to speed up di/dt while charging might be faster of coil L/DCR than a=F/m of magnet velocity ramp but decline inverse squared Force from height/diam. Ratio.>1 and inverse linear loss <<1

Comment: "*I'd first have the electromagnet pulling the piece*". Why ? If you want the piece to go straight up as mentioned in the question, the permanent magnet will be resting on the (switched off) electromagnet due to gravity initially. Then, later, the electromagnet can be activated, pushing the piece straight up against gravity. No need to deal with current reversing.

Comment: To prevent flipping, the you can use some guiding rail or a hollow pipe with inner diameter same size as magnet outer diameter (assuming disc shaped magnet). You can also read up on [coil gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coilgun) even though it is not the exact same concept.

Comment: Sad face, I bought everything to give a shot, and it's a magnificent failure :) It propels the other magnet at... 2cm?

Comment: This probably *is* possible with a sufficiently energetic and rapid discharge.  The coil may not survive, but that might actually be helpful.  Note however that it's probably going to be easier to build something *spring loaded* either launched by releasing a hold down electromagnet, or with a solenoid that releases a physical hold down latch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, [it can not](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4b2omy5EG0). Or at least not with a 400N magnet and a "generic" round magnet

Comment: Incorrect.  What you mean is that it cannot be done with *that* setup.  But that setup is rather obviously weak... you can hear someone flip a little switch.  A system actually designed to do this, would among other things be *loud*.  That little switch would be welded or vaporized... in fact, the switching element might be designed to self destruct.

Comment: The person in the video is I. The flip you can hear is the 230V power plug. The setup is 2 12V power supplies in serie with the magnet connected to them. And yes, obviously it can not be done with the setup I put in place but it might be possible with bigger magnets and possibly a big capacitor to ramp up the voltage like crazy.